# Unwanted animated labels

Tags: r, animation, text, plotly, slider

I get unwanted animated text (that I just wanted to have on hover...) using plot_ly function

`

```
fig <- df %>%
    plot_ly(x = ~x, 
      y = ~value, 
      color = ~variable, 
      frame = ~variable, 
      text = ~paste("Tran: ", x, '<br>Disp:', value, ' m'), 
      hoverinfo = "text",
      type = 'bar') #%>% 
      # add_trace(x = ~x, 
      #           y = ~sp_2020[[h]]$value,
      #           type = 'scatter',
      #           text = ~paste("Text 1: ", x, '<br>Text 2:', round(value, 1), ' m'),
      #           hoverinfo = "text",
      #           mode = 'lines', showlegend = F) 
      # 
    
   
  fig <- fig %>% animation_opts(
    frame =6000, 
    transition = 4000,
    redraw = FALSE
  )
  
 
  fig <- fig %>% animation_slider(
    currentvalue = list(prefix = "Years ", font = list(color="red"))
  )
  
fig
```

`

I use:
RStudio 2022.07.2 Build 576
R version 3.6.1
plotly 4.10.1

Some of the labels of the bars, as I click on play, start moving from the upper left of the plot and settle on the related bar Some others start animating in the bars themselves, as you can see in the next gif!!!

[image]

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: structure(list(x = c("1", "2", "3"), `2005-2017` = c(-8.584610999, 
0, -3.4992811979), `2005-2018` = c(-9.9308735921, 0, 1.8704151967
), `2005-2019` = c(-9.9070524429, 0, -0.0895728345999984), `2005-2020` = c(-10.5080775079, 
-0.0132607871000019, -2.3378541018), `2005-2021` = c(-10.7890185685, 
-0.0132607871000019, -4.8627935479)), row.names = c(1L, 12L, 
23L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Where is `variable` in your `df`?

Comment: sorry, wrog dataset......

Comment: structure(list(x = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 
3), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("2005-2017", "2005-2018", 
"2005-2019", "2005-2020", "2005-2021"), class = "factor"), value = c(-8.58, 
0, -3.5, -9.93, 0, 1.87, -9.91, 0, -0.09, -10.51, -0.01, -2.34, 
-10.79, -0.01, -4.86), type = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 5, 5, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: If you want this text as hover content, then instead of the argument `text`, use `hovertext`. Then delete `hoverinfo`. (You could change it to `hoverinfo = "hovertext"`, but it's unnecessary.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Kat! The code worked last year.... something must have changed meanwhile....

Comment: For anything other than a bar chart, `text` behaves a little differently.